# iPhone: UITableView sections

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a table view with sections.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return numberHigherThen0;
}
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath method I setup my rows according to section

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if (0 == indexPath.section) {
       //setup rows
   } esle {
     //setup rows
   }
}
```

numbers of sections and rows in sections changes dynamically. But numbers of sections always > 0. So in cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath.section == 0 there will be always this case, right ? But some times cellForRowAtIndexPath didn't pass case  indexPath.section == 0 !!! Why ? When it can be true ? When cellForRowAtIndexPath can start count sections from 1 ?

Update:
 section 2 has no rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *numberOfSectionsInTableView:* you specify the number of sections - however, the sections are numbered from **0**.

So if you return 3 in your *numberOfSectionsInTableView* you will have three sections - section 0, section 1, and section 2.

Comment: So why indexPath.section == 0 sometimes never true ?

Comment: The section may not be visible, or the section may not have rows at all?

Comment: The section is visible and it has 1 row

Answer (score 0):

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is only called when the table view needs to refresh a cell at a given index path.

So if section 0 is visible when your app starts, yes, you should get a call with section == 0 at least once. In subsequent refreshes, section 0 might be skipped if UITableView thinks it doesn't need to refresh it. This might be what you're seeing.

Use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, or `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`, etc. to tell the UITableView that a row has changed and that it needs to refresh it.

Comment: "So if section 0 is visible when your app starts, yes, you should get a call with section == 0 at least once. " But I didn't, here is the problem

Comment: Do you return a >0 number to `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` for this section? If the section has no rows, then UITableView won't try to get the rows for it...